# SharePoint 2013 Farm Account: Can it be local, not domain?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, service-account, farm-setup

Finding lots of articles on not making the farm account a member of local administrators, and every article I read about creating accounts refers to a domain user account for the farm account.  But can the farm account be a local (non-administrator) account?

I ask because service accounts on our domain are forced to follow a naming convention, TE0Sxxxx.  With the multitude of accounts required to run SharePoint (with Project and Team Foundation Servers), I'll have to request nearly a dozen accounts and try to keep track of them all with meaningless names.  If I can create them locally, I can name them anything I want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but the setup user/farm user has to be a domain account. You can find more information about this following this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263445.aspx)

Setup user account - Domain user account

Server farm account - Domain user account